# /var/containers/Bundle/Application/<hash>/<app_path>/ Would Like to Use Your Current Location - PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova, geolocation

Building an a PhoneGap app (not sure if that's specifically relevant).

I am getting this message on iOS - I'm guessing it is some path setting or a permission or something?

My config.xml has this for geolocation:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="1.0.1" source="pgb">
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
    </feature>
</plugin>
```

I'm not finding many sources on why this might be happening.

The only answers I can find on SO are about putting your call to navigator into a OnDeviceReady call, but I'm trying that and getting the same message:

```
        <script>
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            function onDeviceReady() {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
}
</script>
```

How do I get rid of this ugly message?

Comment: I have same issue on iOS. But it happen only on any devices. For example on a iPhone 6s with ios 10.3 not happen, and on another same device with same OS happen each time on the start of App